# How to Exclude Specific Hosts from Network Logs in BrowserStack?

Tags: android, automation, browserstack

I am currently working with BrowserStack for automated testing and am trying to refine my network logs by excluding traffic to and from specific hosts. My goal is to exclude all network traffic related to HostName/something from being captured in the network logs. This is crucial for my testing setup as it would help in focusing on the relevant network calls and reduce noise.

I came across the capability or setting that might allow excluding certain hosts from network logs, something similar to `networkLogsExcludeHosts`, but I'm unable to get it to work as expected. Here is an example of how I attempted to configure it:

```
{
  "browserstack.networkLogsExcludeHosts": [
    "Hostname/something",
    "api.example.com/abc"
  ]
}
```

Getting this Error:

> [NETWORK_LOGS_ISSUE] Please specify valid hostnames in browserstack.networkLogsExcludeHosts capability. For more details, please refer to our documentation https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/debug-failed-tests/network-logs.

Comment: A valid hostname error occurs when you have specified an incorrect hostname. This could be due to multiple reasons like adding special characters or something that causes the host name to be invalid. Please share the hostnames you have configured.